# Can't log in to MediaWiKi admin account - no error message

Tags: mediawiki, synology

I recently set up a mediawiki instance on my synology NAS.
Mediawiki version is 1.35.6-1061.

Now I cant log on to the admin account, and there is no feedback I can see on why.

Steps:

1. Navigate to the wiki, I notice that I am no longer logged in. (it says not logged in by a silhouette in the top right corner)
2. I click the log in link in the corner
3. I enter the admin credentials and click the login button.
4. browser returns to wiki main page - still "not logged in" in the corner.

No error message is displayed, and if I try again with the wrong password, it shows a "incorrect password" message, so that's not it.

I only installed it a few days ago, and was definitely logged in for a while and cant be sure when that ended. The WiKi can be edited without an account so I wouldn't have noticed.

I found this:
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:R5xut9pyuuj682du

It seems to be the same symptoms, however its a decade old and the proposed solutions dont work for me either.

Anyone know what might be going on?
Thanks!

Edit - I created normal user account for the Wiki, and was logged in to the account after creation. However, after I logged out of that account and tried to log back in the same thing happens as above.

Comment: First thing to do is check if you allowed cookies. Maybe use a different browser